# How to generate multiple random-spawning scrolling objects in Action Script 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a game for a school project where you jump over objects and collect others. I'm doing this all in the timeline so the .swf file is the only thing that needs to be turned in.

Here is the current code; the last part, 'spawning things' is where I got lost.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

stop();



//intro screen
play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickAway);
function clickAway(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    introScreen.visible = false;
    play_btn.visible = false;
}

//jump
var grav:Number = 8;
var jumping:Boolean = false;
var jumpPow:Number = 0;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

function onKeyDown(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(evt.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
    {
        if(jumping != true)
        {
            jumpPow = -50;
            jumping = true;
        }

    }   
}


function update(evt:Event):void
{
    if(jumping)
    {
        okami_mc.y += jumpPow;
        jumpPow += grav;

        if(okami_mc.y >=300)
        {
            jumping = false;
            okami_mc.y =300;
        }

    }
} 


//make the background move
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, repeat);
function repeat(thing:Event):void
{
    treebg_mc.x -=  13;

    if (treebg_mc.x < -100)
    {
        treebg_mc.x = 1000;
    }

    sun_mc.x -= 5;
    if (sun_mc.x < -100)
    {
        sun_mc.x = 700;
    }
}

//spawning things
bdemon_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bscrollMove);
function bscrollMove(event:Event):void
{
    if (bdemon_mc.x>=-100){
        bdemon_mc.x -=10;
    }else{
        bdemon_mc.x=600;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create hypothetical grids on the stage and randomise the positions on this grid.

```
var randomPoint:RandomPlus = new RandomPlus(0, 4);//number of array elements
var positionXArr:Array     = [0, 50, 100, 150, 200];
var positionYArr:Array     = [200, 300, 400, 500, 600];
var obstaclesArr:Array     = new Array;//push the object that blocks

private function RandomPositioning():void
{
    if(obstaclesArr != null)
    {
        obstaclesArr[0].x = posArray[randomPoint.getNum()];//it is just a random method that ranges between 0 and length of the array.
    }
}
```

and this is the random class by adi feiwel

```
package  
{
    public class RandomPlus 
    {
        private var _st:Number;
        private var _en:Number;
        private var _len:Number;
        private var _pos:Number;
        private var _numPos:Number;
        private var _myNums:Array;
        private var _randNums:Array;

       public function RandomPlus(en:Number, st:Number = 0) 
       {
            _st = st;
            _en = en;

            // just in case if params order mixup:
            if(en < st){
                _st = en;
                _en = st;
            }

            _len = _en - _st + 1;
            shuffle();
        }

        public function getNum():Number
        {
            // if passed last item:
            if(_numPos == _len)shuffle();

            var myResult:Number = _randNums[_numPos];
            _numPos++;
            return myResult;
        }

        private function shuffle():void
        {
            _numPos = 0;
            _randNums = [];
            _myNums = [];

            // Creating Numbers Array:
            var i:Number;
            for(i = 0; i<_len; i++){ _myNums[i] = _st + i; }

            // Creating shuffled Numbers Array:
            i = 0;
            while(_myNums.length > 0){
                _pos = Math.round(Math.random()*(_myNums.length-1));
                _randNums[i] = _myNums[_pos];
                i++;
                _myNums.splice(_pos,1);
            }
        }

        public function get len():Number
        {
            return _len;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you accept an answer if you have no clue what it means?

Comment: @sky Please revise your question (maybe rewrite) then. Because there is a problem with your question and response to the answer. I was thinking the same thing as BotMaster commented. Clarify the problem and do not rush to accept an answer correct.

Comment: sorry, i was frustrated at the time, not thinking